# Azure Policy - Set expiry for keys/secrets

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am trying to write an Azure Policy that checks if a  Azure key has an expiry date, if it does not then I want to do a DeployIfNotExists effect to set one. However I am getting a "ResourceNotFound" error.

Note: The "if" statement without the "then" statement works fine, when I run this policy it shows me which keys do not have a expiration date. Getting the issue when I add in the deployifnotexist effect.

```html
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys/attributes.exp",
          "exists": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys",
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635"
        ],
        "deployment": {
          "properties": {
            "mode": "incremental",
            "template": {
              "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "resources": [
                {
                  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys",
                  "apiVersion": "2021-06-01-preview",
                  "properties": {
                    "exp": "10000"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are working at the Data layer of the Key Vault, what is inside of it (Keys, Secrets, Certificates).

In that case, when it is not about the infrastructure as such (the configuration of the Key Vault itself), you have to use the `Microsoft.KeyVault.Data` mode for your custom policy instead of `All`.

That said, `DeployIfNotExist` policies are not yet supported - see [official documentation about Azure Policy for Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/azure-policy?tabs=certificates). You can only `Audit` or `Deny`.

Comment: If that is the case why does the "if" condition work as expected using the "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys/attributes.exp" field? When evaluating this policy it correctly picks up which keys have an expiration date, if it can do this why can't I modify the expiration date using the same field?

Comment: To my understanding, the "if" block checks for a standalone resource w/o any assumption. When entering the "details" block, the policy engine assumes that there is a parent-child relationship between what you want to deploy and what is scanned, which is not the case here since its the same resource. You might consider using Modify effect instead but looking at the available aliases being "Modifiable" for KeyVault, that is not something you can do either. 
Back to your initial need, I would go for Deny and come up with a script to mitigate existing resources, thats the best I can think of.